# on broadcast encryption

Tags: encryption, broadcast-encryption

I've read the following paper and have one question on it.

[M. Luby and J. Staddon, "Combinatorial Bounds for Broadcast Encryption", EUROCRYPT'98.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.36.6296&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

On page 523 (12th page of the paper) the authors say

> …there are at most $2^{tm}$  petals in $\mathcal{F}$ which don't split any of the blocks, $L_i$.

However, I don't know how they can derive the number $2^{tm}$.  Probably I missed something very easy, but anyway I can't understand.  Anyone here can help me?